# Como alterar o banco de dados do Auth do Laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel, auth, banco-de-dados

Meu projeto possui dois bancos de dados: um banco para conta de usuários e outro para o domínio do projeto. A minha necessidade é definir o banco de dados que o `Auth` utiliza para autenticação, pois na configuração padrão está definido o banco de dados do domínio.

```
return array(

'default' => 'mysql_domain',
```

Queria mudar essa definição acima para o `Auth` e assim ele não utilizar o banco de dados do domínio.

```
'connections' => array(

    'mysql_account' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'user_agro_admin',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'mysql_domain' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'indicator_agro_admin',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    )

),
```

Na configuração do `auth` é possível apenas definir o driver, modelo e a tabela. Minha necessidade poderia ser resolvida apenas se houvesse o método `Auth::setDefaultConnection('mysql_account')` ou algo semelhante. Como fazer isso?

P.S.: Não quero mudar a configuração padrão com o método `Config::set('database.fo', 'bar')`, e sim, alterar o banco de dados que o `Auth` utiliza!

P.S.2.: Utilizo o Query Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Não seria possível apenas alterar a conexão na model User?
Segundo a documentação do Eloquent, é possível fazer isso:

```
protected $connection = 'connection-name';
```

Comment: Desculpa, esqueci de informar que não estou utilizando o Eloquent. Utilizo o Query Builder.

Comment: Algum motivo específico por não estar usando o Eloquent para autenticação? Outra coisa: como tu está fazendo a autenticação? Com Auth::attempt ou manualmente via query builder?

Comment: Acho o Eloquent "engessado" para projetos complexos. Principalmente, quando se trata de fazer consultas com vários relacionamentos. Enfim, é uma questão pessoal. Faço a autenticação com o Auth::attempt e é justamente o problema que estou enfrentado porque o Auth faz a consulta no banco de dados do domínio, porque está definido como o padrão nas configurações.

Comment: Eu já acho o contrário, acho o Eloquent bem poderoso se bem usado, mas enfim, não vem ao caso... Nesse caso, tu tem duas opções: 1- Alterar a configuração em config/auth.php para usar Eloquent (nesse caso, ele usará apenas para a autenticação) e fazer o que comentei acima. 2- Fazer a busca do usuário no banco manualmente via DB::connection('') e depois autenticá-lo via Auth::login($objetoUsuario); Não sei nesse caso é obrigatório uma instância da Model ou não, mas a documentação diz que tem que ser um objeto.

Comment: Mas uma consulta com Query Builder retorna um stdClass e o método login exige um objeto do tipo UserInterface.

Comment: O jeito mais fácil é utilizar o Eloquent, nem que seja apenas para a autenticação, configurando o auth.php adequadamente e criando/alterando a model User. Se mesmo assim tu não quiser usá-lo, o Laravel tem a classe Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser que implementa a interface UserInterface e pode ser usada como "model genérica" no Auth::login(). Essa classe inclusive é usada pelo próprio Laravel ao utilizar o driver "database" para autenticação. Veja: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.18/src/Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php#L100

Comment: Como meu prazo está curto optei pela simplicidade. Modifiquei a configuração padrão do arquivo database.php para mysql_account e assim o Auth consegue fazer autenticação apenas utilizando o método usual attempt. E nos meus modelos utilizo o método connection, por exemplo, DB::connection('mysql_domain')->table('servers')::get(). Enfim, não era o que queria exatamente mas consegui utilizar dois banco de dados no projeto. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Mas por que tu não usa o Eloquent apenas para a autenticação? Mantém o database.php do jeito que estava e ajusta apenas o auth.php para usar o Eloquent. Cria uma model para o usuário (que extende o Eloquent) e utiliza ela apenas para autenticar. Isso não vai impactar em nada no teu projeto e é ainda mais simples que a tua solução...

Comment: Trauma após usá-lo para consultas complexas.

Comment: Cara, o Eloquent será usado APENAS na autenticação, sem impacto NENHUM para o resto da aplicação. Já a tua solução terá impacto em qualquer recurso que usa a conexão default, isso inclui o comando "php artisan migrate", que nesse caso fará a migração na base errada... Se mesmo assim quiser manter desse jeito, beleza. Mas tenha ciência que pode gerar mais problemas.

Comment: Não, coloco as migrations em diretórios específicos e quando executo o comando artisan migrate adiciono o curinga path.

Comment: @galegostigma sua solução trará problemas maiores para sua aplicação. Se você der uma olhada em https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent verá que é bem simples e poderoso o eloquent. Você consegue fazer querys bem complexas.

Comment: @MateusAzevedo concordo com você +1 :)